# How to create LineStringField in MongoEngine?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, geolocation, mongoengine

I would like to know how to create an object with a [LineStringField](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.LineStringField) in MongoEngine.
With a model like that:

```
class Line(Document):
    line = LineStringField()
    owner = ReferenceField(User)

    meta = {
        'indexes': [[("line", "2dsphere"), ("owner", 1)]]
    }
```

I would do something like that:

```
shape = Line(owner=user, line={type:"LineString",coordinates:[[0,2],[2,0],[2.5,1.2]]})
shape.save()
```

But I feel like I am overwriting the preset "type" attribute of the predefined LineStringField.

Comment: What about `shape.line.coodinates` notation ? Haven't checked the code as yet. Just a guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either pass a dictionary with the full geoJSON information or a list of point pairs. eg:

```
Line(owner=user, line=[[0,2],[2,0],[2.5,1.2]]).save()
```

Comment: Sorry, I just realized it is written in the doc.